# I didn't get response from the nodejs server. It showing undefine after request to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, webserver

**I hosted website on two different platforms like Firebase and Heroku**
**I Have some issues with that**

1. Firstly, It showing cors errors when I post data from firebase hosted URL to the server which is hosted on Heroku
2. Then after resolving cors errors data couldn't from the server it showing undefined in console
   **Here is my server-side code which is hosted on Heroku**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.json({limit:'1mb'}))

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://sample-377b8.web.app');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With,content-type,Accept,Authorization',);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
if(req.method=="OPTIONS"){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH')
  return res.status(200).json({})
}
// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});
let data;
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.send("hello world")
}) 
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
 
  data = req.body
 console.log(data)
 res.status(200).json({
  "success":"200 response",
  "res":"You are now just talked with server" 
 })

})


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

**This is my client side code**

```
document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click',async()=>{
           let data = {lat,lon}
            await fetch('https://demoserver-app.herokuapp.com/',{mode:"no-cors"},{
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
           }).then( async (dat) =>{
             console.log(res.json())
           }).then(res =>{
               console.log(res)
           })
       })
```

It is giving the error on a console like
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy3WJ.jpg) image

Headers information in the network tab
[Header information of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ1gb.jpg) image

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you,
one issue that I see that can make this kind of output
is that you console.log(res) but .then referring to (dat)
And I don''t think you need async inside .then(it's already async function)
try this:

```html
document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click',async()=>{
           let data = {lat,lon}
            await fetch('https://demoserver-app.herokuapp.com/',{mode:"no-cors"},{
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
           }).then( data =>{
             data.json()
           }).then(res =>{
               console.log(res)
           })
       })
```

Comment: thank for your response, I tried this but it shows again error like *** Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input***

Comment: And also shows undefine in the console. please check the demo project here [demo project](https://sample-377b8.web.app/)

Comment: It seems working just fine with Postman, but still not fetching, but still, couldn't resolve the problem on the client.

Comment: Postman allow for this types of cors because it doesn't a browser but any alternative please

Answer (score 0):

ok, so for the server side:
1)you need to destructure data from req.body, what you made is just adjust req.body to data bar.(see my solution)
2) for the post method you need to make a directory and not try it in the root directory.
try this code you will see the response you want
server:

```html
app.post('/getmessage', (req,res) => {
    const {data} = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).json({
        "success":"200 response",
        "res":"You are now just talked with server" 
       })
})
```

client:

```html
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/getmessage', {
        method : 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
         data:"this is massage from client"
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
       .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: yeah it's working but I not getting JSON response in-app my code on server side ``````

Comment: yeah it's working but I am not getting JSON response in web. My code on server-side routes `routes.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.send("this is post requist")
})routes.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const {data} = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).json({
        "success":"200 response",
        "res":"You are now just talked with server" 
       })
})`  <br/> But in console they showing error same as previous and another response is , In the network preview tab actually I getting a message which is written in **get** router above  written get router

Comment: maybe because your data from the client is a nester object, if so, try to destructor them too. if you send from cline {email: 'pranav@gmail.com'} then in server you make const {email} = req.body;

Comment: but it's work fine with same origin client side
. I got only problem with cross origin client side